# Help! Am I specifying my mixed-effects model formula correctly?

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I have a dataset where 50 Subjects were each exposed to 2 Testing Conditions over 5 Time Periods and they reported their Happiness Levels at every time point (i.e., I have 50 * 2 * 5 Happiness data points in total). Based on past work, I know I need to run a "*linear mixed-effects model with a fully specified random-effects structure, with subjects as a non-nested random factor, and all intercepts and slopes included*".

If I just had 50 Subjects with 5 Time Periods, I know that my lme4 formula would be:

```
Happiness ~ Time + (Time | Subjects)
```

But if I have 50 Subjects with 5 Time Periods AND 2 Testing Conditions, would this be:

```
Happiness ~ Time * TestingCondition + (Time * TestingCondition | Subjects)
```

I'm still learning more complicated LMM designs at the moment, so if I'm completely off the mark here, I'd appreciate any help or advice I can get!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is almost right, although it probably needs to be adjusted for practical/identifiability purposes. The rubric is that any condition or treatment that varies *within* groups should be allow to vary *across* groups; since you have measurements for both testing conditions and every time point for every subject, you can in principle measure the variation of all of these effects (for example: "how does the difference in testing conditions at time point 3 vary across subjects?" [this quantity isn't *explicitly* estimated by the model]).

There are a few important points to consider, however, in two cases.

### `Time` considered as categorical

In this case you have two problems:

- since you only have one measurement per time point $\times$ treatment combination per subject, the among-subject variance in the interaction is confounded with the residual variance term. There are a few different options for overriding this, but ...
- in addition, your model will almost certainly be overparameterized/too complex. With two time points and 5 treatments, you have 10 parameters that vary across subjects, which implies a 10 $\times$ 10 covariance matrix with (10*11)/2 = 55 parameters to estimate. It's *extremely* unlikely that you will be able to do this with 50 subjects/500 data points ... you could:

  - use a Bayesian framework (e.g. `blme`, `MCMCglmm`, or `brms`) to put regularizing priors on the covariance matrix
  - simplify the model, at least to `(Time + Treatment|Subject)` (this will "only" require a 6 $\times$ 6 covariance matrix with 21 parameters ...)
  - simplify in some other way, e.g. use `glmmTMB` to fit a factor-analytic covariance matrix, or `afex::mixed` to fit a zero-covariance model

### `Time` considered as continuous

This version is much easier, although it requires you to assume a linear trend across time points.

Now `(Treatment*Time|Subject)` only implies a 4 $\times$ 4 covariance matrix = 10 parameters.  Still a little bit ambitious, but it might work.

Comment: This is wonderful, thank you for the detailed answer Ben! So if I'm understanding this correctly: (1) if I consider Time to be categorical, my formula would be "Happiness ~ Time * Testing + (Time + Testing | Subject)" to account for the overcomplexity of my model OR (2) if I consider Time to be continuous, my formula would be "Happiness ~ Time * Testing + (Time * Testing | Subject)"?

Comment: Yes, although you might not be entirely out of the woods - either of these models might still be too complex for the data.

Comment: Okay good to know, thanks a bunch for the quick responses @BenBolker, and I'll definitely look into whether I'll need to simplify the model further!

Comment: If this solved your problem you are encouraged to click on the check-mark to accept it ..